# Protractor 5.1.1- Chai assertion failure is causing process to exit with error code: 199. No reports are generating after that

Tags: protractor, chai, cucumberjs

cucumber framework. When a chai assertion is failed, the process is exiting with error code:199. No reports are generated after that.

Protractor - 5.1.1

Here is my updated code,

```
this.Then(/^I should see process is saved in db$/, function (next) {
  var sql = "select * from process where name = ?";
    sql = mysql.format(sql, params.flow.procName);
    console.log(sql);

    dbConn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields){

        if(!err) {
            procDbObj = rows;
            var procName = procDbObj[0].name;
            console.log(rows);
            expect(procDbObj[0].name).to.equal(params.flow.procName);
            expect(procDbObj[0].description).to.equal(params.flow.procDesc);
            expect(procName).to.equal("AABBDCD").and.notify(next);
        }
     });
});
```

Below is the error I am seeing when an assertion is failed,

**[11:23:59] E/launcher - expected 'Auto_proc_2h5c83' to equal 'AABBDCD'
[11:23:59] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected 'Auto_proc_2h5c83' to equal 'AABBDCD'
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\features\step_definitions\E2E_step_definition.js:64:34)**
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:86:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:137:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:121:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:75:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket. (C:\Users\panubrolu\workspace\ProtractorCucumber\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)

**[11:23:59] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199**

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few problems in your code.

**1:** It the db-query a Promise? You are using Callback (`next`) and Promises ('return') at the same time. If it is a Promise then the code should be something like this

```
this.Then(/^I should see process is saved in db$/, function () {
  var sql = "select * from process where name = ?";
    sql = mysql.format(sql, params.flow.procName);
    console.log(sql);

    return dbConn.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields){

        if(!err) {
            procDbObj = rows;
            var procName = procDbObj[0].name;
            console.log(rows);
            expect(procDbObj[0].name).to.eventually.equal(params.flow.procName);
            expect(procDbObj[0].description).to.eventually.equal(params.flow.procDesc);
        } else {
            return Promise.reject('Query Failed, error = ' + err);
        }
    });
});
```

**2:** If it is a promise, did you also use `chai` and `chai-as-promised`?

**3:** If you are using a `callback`, then you should 'notify' Cucumber that the scenario is done, you can do that with `expect('foo').to.equal('bar').and.notify(next);`

**4:** You don't have a promise / callback when the query fails, see the `Promise.reject('message')` in the first point

Hope this will give you some info for debugging you problem.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for the code update. The question I have was, when an assertion is failed in my code, i am seeing below error and the process exit with errorcode 199.